# Proximity Alert - Starting activity

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm using Proximity Alert to start an activity.

I had this working on my Android 2.3 emulator with GPS support but after having restarted PC it is no longer working.  Not sure if it's due to buggy Eclipse.

I must be missing something in my code or broke it and can't see it now:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
double lat = 33.426517;
double lon = -70.439244;
float radius = 1000f;
long expiration = -1;

 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Instantiate MapView, ZoomControls, layout, etc. here
    */
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration,
            pendingIntent);

    Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newActivity, 0);

    }
```